# How to get text from editText that is on the recycle view adapter at some position

Tags: android

I have an edit text at 5th position on recyclerview adapter. I need to get text from that edittext on a click of button (button is on the fragment of adapter and I need that text on that fragment

Answer (score 0):

Create interface in your adapter.

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
```

You can implement method of interface in Recycler View Holder class of your adapter to get the text of card view as per your requirement.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(),v);
        imageView_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        });
}
```

Now, create a global static object of class ClickListner and pass it in click listner method on card clicked. Now get edittext text from particular card view on its click.

```
 //Create global reference
 private static ClickListener clickListener;
```

create method to detect the click in recycler view from fragment.

```
 public void setOnItemClickListner(ClickListener clickListner) {
    MainAdapter.clickListener = clickListner;
}
```

Now you can get the text from edit text from from bind view holder

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final MainModel mainModel = modelList.get(position);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            editText.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

It will work for you.

Comment: I solved that...this will not work...i tried interface before but it will not work coz my submit button is in the fragment. when i click on that i need to call Adapter view holder inside onClick method.if i call adapter it will be done after the completion of that onClick method.but at the end of this method my api gets hit.so i had to do it other way around.Thanks by the way.